# Bitly APIv4 spreadsheet integration

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently using the now deprecated BITLY API v3 to generate links in a google spreadsheet using the following guides

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1553PlJ22cUfs0a_SMa49V7TBDchbqd5gL7iR6UBaR-s/edit#gid=0
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3442741?hl=en

It works very well, but is about to stop as v3 is going offline. I am struggling to find a similar guide for the new v4 API.

https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004395631-Migrating-from-v3-to-v4-of-the-Bitly-API

Any ideas of how to recreate the functionality I have with v3 using the new v4 API? Answers much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you put this question to Bitly Support/Community?